# MySql Triggers Error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have 2 tables in MySql `dealers` and `dealers_info`. I try to create trigger which after deleting info from `dealers` will delete corresponding rows from `dealers info`

```
CREATE TRIGGER del_info AFTER DELETE ON  dealers
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM dealers_info WHERE dealer_id = OLD.dealer_id;
END;
```

But I've got an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the delimiter to execute the query properly,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER del_info 
AFTER DELETE ON  dealers
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM dealers_info WHERE dealer_id = OLD.dealer_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```